# Division algorithm proof equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

On the following [website](http://www.mathpath.org/concepts/divisionalgo.htm) there is a statement:

$$a - ba = -a(b-1)$$

$a$ is negative and $b$ is positive. How does this rearrangement happen? I see that it is equal, but I can not see how to algebraically get it. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you can see they're equal, then what else do you want?

Comment: $a - ba = -ba + a = -a(b - 1)$

Comment: It is  $\ {-}c+bc = c(b-1)\ $ for $\, c = -a,\,$ i.e. pull out a factor of $\,c\,$ via the **Distributive Law** (which is true for *all* integers, not only positive integers).

Comment: Ok, let's say that we didn't know the signs of $a$ and $b$. Then we would arrange them like this $a - ba = -ba + a = a(-b + 1)$. In the question case the author put the minus sign in front of the $a$ because he knew it was negative and then factored it out. Am I right about this?

Comment: It doesn't matter if $a$ is negative or not. If $a=2$, then $2-b\cdot 2 = -2(b-1)$ and if $a=-2$, $(-2)-b(-2) = -(-2)(b-1)$.

Comment: What I don't understand how $-2b +2=-2(b-1)$. How $-2$ gets factored out if the other one is positive?

Answer (score 1):

Since we have $$-a(b-1)=-a\cdot b-a\cdot (-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

In a commutative ring such as the integers, $(-a)(-b) = ab$, $(-a)b = a(-b) = -ab$.
Using this and distributivity, $-a(b-1) = (-a)(b+(-1)) = (-a)b + (-a)(-1) = -ab +a$.

Comment: When going from $-ab + a$ to $-a(b-1)$ how does $-a$ get factored out? Check my comment on the question also.